# Couchbase N1QL Update Array of Strings into Array of Objects

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am trying to update an array of strings into an array of objects in Couchbase using N1QL.  I would like to take the following structure:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "items": [
      "one",
      "two",
      "three"
   ]
}
```

And transform it into:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "items": [
      {
         "id": "some-uuid-001",
         "value": "one"
      },
      {
         "id": "some-uuid-002",
         "value": "two"
      },
      {
         "id": "some-uuid-003",
         "value": "three"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am on Couchbase 4.6 and would like to use N1QL only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question:

```
update bucket
set bucket.items[i] = {"id": UUID(), "value": bucket.items[i]} 
FOR i:sb IN bucket.items END
where id = 1;
```